LazyColumn overlay propagate touch event underneath
I have a LazyColumn that sits on top of the whole screen as an overlay. I want to programmatically control whether the view underneath receives the touch event or the LazyColumn itself.
Here's the overlay Composable:
Box (
   modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .alpha(0.5f)
   ) {
       LazyColumn(
          modifier = Modifier
              .fillMaxSize(),
                userScrollEnabled = false
            ) {
               ....
            }
        }

If I make the LazyColumn a Box, the touch goes through. I tried focusable(false) and clickable(false){} on the Modifier with no success.

In jetpack compose gestures propagate from descendant to ancestor in parent child relationship when pointerEventPass is set as Main which is the default one for default gestures or clickables. By changing pass to Initial you can have Box get down or move events before LazyColumn or its children. You can refer this answer for more details about how gesture system works.
I also answered similar question, for a Modifier to get touch and move events before pager here.
And by conditionally calling PointerInputChange.consume() you can prevent other Composables or Modifiers getting touch events.
And if you wish to add ripple effect you can use MutableInteractionSource and getting position from awaitFirstDown()
Result

Demo
@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyColumnTouchPropagationTest() {

    val interactionSource = remember {
        MutableInteractionSource()
    }

    var isBoxReceiveEvents by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                isBoxReceiveEvents = isBoxReceiveEvents.not()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Box receives events: $isBoxReceiveEvents")
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .pointerInput(isBoxReceiveEvents) {
                    if (isBoxReceiveEvents) {
                        coroutineScope {
                            awaitEachGesture {
                                val down = awaitFirstDown(
                                    pass = PointerEventPass.Initial
                                )

                                // Consuming down prevent other Modifiers to
                                // get first down event
                                down.consume()

                                val press = PressInteraction.Press(down.position)

                                // This is for showing ripple on touch
                                // this optional to show you can show ripple as well
                                launch {
                                    interactionSource.emit(press)
                                }

                                val up = waitForUpOrCancellation(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)


                                up?.let {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Box is touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                                launch {
                                    interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .indication(interactionSource, ripple())
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                userScrollEnabled = false,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp)
            ) {
                items(20) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Red)
                            .clickable {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Row $it, clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            }
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        text = "Row $it",
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

You can also change last part as
up?.let {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Box is touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show()

    launch {
        interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))
    }
}?:run {
    launch {
        interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Cancel(press))
    }
}

If you wish to handle cancel indication as well.

Since this example is written with jetpack Compose 1.7.0-beta03 i use ripple() instead of rememberRipple

Thanks but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I want the LazyList to not even respond to events. Let it pass through to whatever is underneath. The issue for me is that underneath is a Fragment, and I'm not sure if there's an issue way to propagate the touch events

Additionally, if I just add a Box, the touch events seem to go through. Event if I add a Text it starts capturing the events.

Events go through from child to parent with PointerEventPass.Main which is the default one. And if you consume it you stop relevant event at that modifier. My example shows how Box underneath gets events first and consumes them so LazyColumn or any of its children don't get events or you use default one which lets event pass from LazyColumn children to LazyColumn then to Box.

Additionally, if I just add a Box, the touch events seem to go through. of course they go through with default one. This example shows how you can alo reverse propagation and cancel it at some point or use default one.

I want to programmatically control whether the view underneath receives the touch event or the LazyColumn itself. This answers the or part. If you want to stop events at LazyColumn you should add similar modifier to LazyColumn and consume at that point. But since you want LazyColumn to receive it first you can leave pass at Main
